# How to test an active TCP socket if it is still alive or not

Tags: powershell, network-programming

We suspect that a firewall between two servers is dropping our TCP connection too early without notifying the servers and we would like to know if it is possible to make use of PowerShell to do so. We know that from time to time the connections are dropped and our application tries to use what it thinks is an active socket, but after some delay it close it and opens a new one, which is causing delay.

To get a general idea, we tried to pass the output of `Get-NetTcpConnection` to `Test-Connection`, but obviously it didn't work.

Is it possible to use PowerShell to get a list of "Established" connections and sent a PING or any test request to get the actual status of the socket or to see if it is alive or not?

Comment: Local sockets provide no information about the state of a connection on a firewall en route.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, a local socket on your computer does not provide any information about the state of that connection on a firewall en route. Also, while you can enumerate established connections locally and then probe them, that will not produce the result you're looking for. Not only is `Test-Connection` not the right tool (it sends ICMP probes, not TCP probes, i.e. operates in the wrong layer), but even if you use `Test-NetConnection` (which supports TCP probes) that would establish a *new* connection, not re-use the one your application is using.

Essentially, the only way to check the state of a connection on a firewall is to check the state of the connection on the firewall.

With that said, the most likely reason for a firewall dropping a connection prematurely is diverging TCP keepalive settings on firewall and connection endpoints, at least in my experience. Windows has a default [TCP keepalive time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd349797(v=ws.10)#keepalivetime) of 2 hours, whereas many firewalls default to a shorter keepalive time (like 30 minutes).

The keepalive time of Windows systems can be changed in the registry, e.g. by importing a .reg file with the following content (0x493e0 == 300000 ms == 6 min):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]
"KeepAliveTime"=dword:000493e0
```